# Understanding PromQL in grafana dashboard

Tags: django, prometheus, grafana, django-prometheus

I am trying out django dashboards for grafana. I imported a [django dashbord from grafana.com](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/17658-django/). It has following panel:

[image]

(I have greyed out my app view names) The PromQL query is as follows:

```
topk(20, 
    (1 - 
        (sum(max_over_time(django_http_requests_latency_seconds_by_view_method_bucket{app=~"^$application$",le="$threshold"}[$__range]) 
                        / ignoring(le) max_over_time(django_http_requests_latency_seconds_by_view_method_count{app=~"^$application$"}[$__range])) 
        by (method, view) / count(present_over_time(django_http_requests_latency_seconds_by_view_method_count{app=~"^$application$"}[$__range])) by (method, view))) > 0.0099)
```

Also, the bar gauge does not change as long as I select "Last X", i.e. from "Last day" to "Last Year". **Q1.** Is it because all data is generated in last day it is convered in "Last Year" and the query takes Max over whole range?

**Q2.** Can someone help me understand this PromQL? Is it returning slowest view in given time range?

**Q3.** Also what is ">1s" in its title bar?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [this post](https://grafana.com/blog/2020/02/04/introduction-to-promql-the-prometheus-query-language/) to understand PromQL better.  This is a moderately complex query that needs a lot of "unpacking" in order to describe exactly what it does, but broadly -- yes it's trying to find the slowest responding views in your django app.

Broadly, the query has many "pieces" to understand separately.

- Specific metrics like `django_http_requests_latency_seconds_by_view_method_count{app=~"^$application$"}[$__range]` which is a reference to a particular metric, matching a particular label (for the application referenced by variable `$application$`, in a given time range `[$__range]` set by the dashboard
- Aggregation operators (like `topk`) which you can [read about more here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators)
- [Vector matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) like `ignoring`

> Also, the bar gauge does not change as long as I select "Last X", i.e. from "Last day" to "Last Year"

Hard to answer this one because it depends on your data.  Maybe the slowest views are still the slowest views over a wider timeframe?  To investigate why it does/doesn't change, break the query down, use "Explore" mode and see what the data actually says.

> Q3. Also what is ">1s" in its title bar?

I think what they're going for there is that only views that took more than one second to respond are included in this.  So if all of your views were super fast & perfomant, and the slowest was 0.5 sec, you would hope to see an empty display here, I think.